# Handlebars.NET in .NET Core not filling in data in a simple example

Tags: c#, .net-core, handlebars.js

I have a .NET 5 app that is trying to use Handlebars.NET. Right now, I'm just doing a very basic example to make sure it works, and it currently doesn't.

I have added the Nuget Handlebars.NET, but nothing else.

Here's my template:

```
   <script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h1>Data Report for {{customer}}</h1>
    <h2>Tenant: {{tenant}}</h2>

    <p>
        This is for testing.
    </p>
   </script>
```

Here's my context:

```
var context = "{ \"customer\" : \"mycustomer\", \"tenant\" : \"mytenant\" }";
```

Here's the C# code I'm using:

```
        var template = Handlebars.Compile( html ); // contains the above template
        string finalHtml = template( context );
```

The resulting text stored in finalHtml looks like this:

```
   <script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h1>Data Report for </h1>
    <h2>Tenant: </h2>

    <p>
        This is for testing.
    </p>
   </script>
```

My goal was for {{customer}} to be replaced with my mycustomer and {{template}} to be replaced with mytemplate, but they're being replaced with empty strings, it seems.

Can anyone see if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't your context be an object instead of string `var context = new {customer = "mycustomer", tenant = "mytenant"};`. Please refer - https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net

Comment: @VineetDesai That was it. I don't know why I never saw the examples you pointed me to. I looked all over and never saw those. Not sure why. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `context` should be an object and not a string.

```
var context = new {customer = "mycustomer", tenant = "mytenant"};
```

Please refer the documentation - https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net